# How to write mock for file download for unit tests

Tags: python, python-requests, mocking

I am using `requests_mock` as the library to test code I write that consumes endpoints.

This is my `download_file` function

```
def download_as_file(url: str, auth=(), file_path="", attempts=2):
    """Downloads a URL content into a file (with large file support by streaming)

    :param url: URL to download
    :param auth: tuple containing credentials to access the url
    :param file_path: Local file name to contain the data downloaded
    :param attempts: Number of attempts
    :return: New file path. Empty string if the download failed
    """
    if not file_path:
        file_path = os.path.realpath(os.path.basename(url))
    logger.info(f"Downloading {url} content to {file_path}")
    url_sections = urlparse(url)
    if not url_sections.scheme:
        logger.debug("The given url is missing a scheme. Adding http scheme")
        url = f"https://{url}"
        logger.debug(f"New url: {url}")
    for attempt in range(1, attempts + 1):
        try:
            if attempt > 1:
                time.sleep(10)  # 10 seconds wait time between downloads
            with requests.get(url, auth=auth, stream=True) as response:
                response.raise_for_status()
                with open(file_path, "wb") as out_file:
                    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024 * 1024):  # 1MB chunks
                        out_file.write(chunk)
                logger.info("Download finished successfully")
                return (response, file_path)
        except Exception as ex:
            logger.error(f"Attempt #{attempt} failed with error: {ex}")
    return None
```

How do I test this with `requests_mock`?

I know the documentation for `requests_mock` covers the following at https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/response.html#registering-responses

> To specify the body of the response there are a number of options that depend on the format that you wish to return.
>
> - json:   A python object that will be converted to a JSON string.
> - text:   A unicode string. This is typically what you will want to use for regular textual content.
> - content:    A byte string. This should be used for including binary data in responses.
> - body:   A file like object that contains a .read() function.
> - raw:    A prepopulated urllib3.response.HTTPResponse to be returned.
> - exc:    An exception that will be raised instead of returning a response.

Is it body or content? And how do I write it?

Most endpoints give me json, but I have this particular use case of downloading a `.xlsx` file, so I want to write a test case for consuming it.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Choose body

Long answer:

```
with requests_mock.mock() as m:
    current_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    path = os.path.join(
        current_folder, filename
    )
    with open(path, "rb") as the_file:
        m.get(url_to_mock, body=the_file)
```